# How to Fragments keeping running on Navigate?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

I have an Android application that has two or more fragments. One of them needs to get a temperature sample from a Microcontroller continuously, so it must keep running forever, even when the fragment is replaced, the question is: How to implement this?

In my application every time I need to navigate, I replace the fragment, but `FragmentManager.beginTransction().replace` remove my instance and the Thread is stopped. How to navigate without the removal or stopping of the service?
Also, I am using `Attach` method, but the fragments stay overlayed in the layout.

Comment: The answer is in your question. Use a service to capture the temp. change.

Comment: Is that the only way?

Comment: Do you want it to run only when your app is running or even after your app exits?